# What is the difference between $x=\sqrt{x}$, $x^2=x$, and $x=\pm\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\begin{align}
x &= \sqrt{x} \tag1 \\[4pt]
x^2 &= x \tag2 \\[4pt]
x &=  \pm\sqrt{x} \tag3
\end{align}$$

What is the difference between equations $1$ and $3$?

If I were asked to find the value of $x$, and if I only solved using equation $1$, I get only one value. But if I solve using the equation $3$, I get two values of $x$. How to choose then ?

$$\begin{align}
1 &= \sqrt{1} \tag1 \\[4pt]
1^2 &= 1 \tag2 \\[4pt]
1 &=  \pm\sqrt{1} \tag3
\end{align}$$

The first equation has two solutions.0 and 1.

For 1st equation x = 0 and 1.

For 2nd equation , same 0and 1 only.

For 3rd we have , 0 = +- square root of 0.So it is only 0. But for 1 , it 1 = +- square root of 1.That is -1 and 1 since square root of 1 is 1only.

So total solutions = 1,-1,0. Now where am I wrong ?

Comment: I see three equations.

Comment: I want to difference in last and 1st one mainly

Comment: @1613585 just to show how I solved it.It is very much relevant

Comment: @Tavish check my edit pls.

Comment: You seem to be confused: it's true that $3=\sqrt9$.  But $3$ is definitely no solution of $x=\sqrt x$ as $3\neq\sqrt3$.

Comment: I have written 3 = root 9

Comment: Ohk.You mean to say I cannot write x as 9 and 3.I need to only write 3.@MichaelHoppe

Comment: Ok.@MichaelHoppe now I again have two values in 3

Comment: Did you read the first paragraph of my answer carefully?

Comment: I removed it right.I added 1 then as x

Comment: The first equation has two solutions, don't you see that? Substituting $0$ and $1$ for $x$ gives true statements.  What do you mean by *choose*?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting confused. The plus or minus sign in the third equation does *not* mean there are two solutions in *that* equation.

When you solve both equation you have

$$ x^2 = x $$

Which has two solutions, 0 and 1. If you plug them in to both equation s you get that the solutions 0 and 1 do work.

---

The reason why $-1$ isn't a solution is because you can't do $\sqrt{-1}$ without entering the realm of complex numbers.

Also, $(-1)^2 \not= -1$.

---

I still don't think you understand the meaning of ${\displaystyle \pm }$. It means that it is either $+$ or $-$.

The third equation really says either:

$$ x = \sqrt{x}$$
or
$$ x = -\sqrt{x}$$.

Now understand?

Comment: Ok.I have solved it by putting values.Just check edit

Comment: I have written it in my edit

Comment: Ohk.I have read your answer.

Comment: By the way I edited it once again.

Comment: Ok.So you mean to say that we have to choose one value.We don’t know that value as well.So we put in equation and then find out right.

Comment: So it means to choose either of them right.Either + 1 or -1

Comment: First of all, before choosing, check which of $0, 1$ and $-1$ are correct. Only $0$ and $1$ are correct.

Comment: Ok.Thank you for helping.That was the main point was I was confused.Yes , it did hurt a lot when you said my comments are stupid.But ok then.You even helped till end.

Comment: @user282657: You *must* accept it. This prevents others from thinking that this answer is still unanswered!

Answer (score 2):

All three are statement forms. The *solution set* of a statement form is the set of all objects that turns the statement form in a *true statement* if the statement form's placeholder is substituted by that object.  If two statement form share the same solution set they're called *equivalent*.

The first one reads: "A number equals its square root."

The second one reads: "A number equals its square."

The third reads:" A number is either its root or its negative root."  as $x=\pm\sqrt x$ is just an abbreviation for $x=+\sqrt x\lor x=-\sqrt x$.

The solution set clearly is $\{0,1\}$ in all cases.

All three statement forms are equivalent.

EDIT (for the third equation): If a number equals its square root, it must be $1$ or $0$.  If a number equals its negative root it must be $0$.  Hence the solution set again is $\{0,1\}$.

EDIT2: All solutions of $x=\sqrt x$ must be non-negative as the square root is only defined for non-negative numbers. For non-negative numbers $x$ we therefore know $x=\sqrt{x}^2$ by definition of the square root. Now
$$\begin{align}x=\sqrt x&\iff x-\sqrt x=0\iff \sqrt{x}^2-\sqrt x=0\\
&\iff\sqrt x(\sqrt x-1)=0\iff \sqrt x=0\lor \sqrt x=1\\
&\iff x=0\lor x=1.\end{align}$$
Treat the other equations similarly.

Comment: If it asks me value of x , if I only solve till 1st equation , I get only value but if I solve till 3rd equation , I get two values of x.How to choose then

Comment: @user282657 Huh? There are two values of x in *all* the equations.

Comment: No. How sir ? In 1st one there is only value of x that is root x

Comment: In 3rd one , it is +- root x

Comment: @user282657: You are getting confused. The first and last equation are **different**, so it sounds reasonable that they have different number of solutions, as of now.

Comment: @user282657 In the first equation you are dividing by x so you ignore the solution x=0.

Comment: Please check my edit with values now.We got two different values in 3 and only one value in 1sr

Comment: @ultralegend5385 pls check my edit now